# how can i work with wow.min.js in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to work with wordpress.I have added some js files using enque _script function and it also added the files before body tag.but it is not working as it is working as html page.

like the wow.min.js, jquery.prettyPhoto.js, jquery.flexslider-min.js and waypoints.js these files are not working.

but when I am saving that redering wordpress file as html and running that html from anywhere from my computer it is then working with all animation of wow.min.js files and also showing the slider of jquery.flexslider-min.js .

what may be problem can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you're probably using the $() jQuery notation, which Wordpress doesn't like since it runs jQuery in No Conflict mode for compatibility reasons. Thus plugins using $() don't tend to work.

Try either using find replace on the plugin files and change instances of '$(' to 'jQuery(', or re-register jQuery with out no-conflict enabled.

Check here for more info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: this is my jQuery file [https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6FfsB50Y6H-el9LMldDbEo3STg](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6FfsB50Y6H-el9LMldDbEo3STg)
.
i also added var $ = jQuery.noConflict(); in first line but it did not work

Comment: Using 'var $ = jQuery.noConflict()' wont help you because it's just reassigning the $ as the jQuery alias. Also, it's wordpress' jQuery library file running in noConflict that's the issue, not the plugin file. You can de-register wordpress' jQuery in your functions file, and register the default version with $ enabled, or you can replace the $ in all the plugin files with jQuery (which is what I've done in smaller plugins. Kind of brute forcey but gets the job done.) and your plugins should work.

Comment: wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() .'/scripts/jquery.min.js',false,'1.10',true);
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

      like this?

Comment: please see this screenshot, how i have used it.
http://prntscr.com/8ky687      , but it is not till now working

Comment: Hey sorry for the delay, fell asleep. Glad you got it working. JQuery and WP don't always play nicely without some reconfiguring.